# java.lang.StackOverflowError in intellij even after changing Xss property

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am getting below error while creating package in intellij. I have case class with many parameters around 240 columns.

Error:
s

```
cala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5478)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedSelectOrSuperCall$1(Typers.scala:4812)
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) java.lang.StackOverflowError
[error] Total time: 31 s, completed Jan 12, 2019 11:00:53 PM

I have already updated vmoption file as below but this error is still coming.
# custom IntelliJ IDEA VM options

-Xms30G
-Xmx30G
-Xss30G
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow


I already updated my vmoption file with below parameters and updated Xss and Xmx in settings.

# custom IntelliJ IDEA VM options

-Xms30G
-Xmx30G
-Xss30G
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
```

I have compiled the code and I am not getting any error in compile but when I create package I am getting this error.

Comment: seems like you are trying to execute mvn clean package or sbt goal from intellij in this case you need to edit the setting of mvn plugin or sbt plugin to accommodate jvm parameters for the corresponding tool not intellij. Intellij settings might be correct but your package goal may not be using that.

Comment: If you're compiling using sbt, you should make sure it runs in a VM that has those parameters. I usually run sbt standalone so I don't know how IntelliJ instantiates its own sbt.

Answer (score 0):

I got he answer I have to update sbt file in my program file with -Xss2G and -Xmx2G and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was confused earlier by Pawan's answer but what I believe he meant is this setting in IDEA Intellij ( and not the SBT file itself )

Intellij IDEA > Preferences > Build,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > sbt

you can set following:

```
-Xss8m
```

The most confusing thing here is that it seems that this is different from Scala Compiler Server ( for which I tried a lot of combinations and even tried changing the underlying JDK and what not ) but the key was that that the sbt shell was not getting affected by those changes

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -server -Xmx1536M -Dsbt.supershell=false -Xss8m -Didea.managed=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  ....
```

thus i searched for SBT properties.